# ext-all-debug.js vs ext-all-dev.js

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

What is the main difference between ext-all-debug.js and ext-all-dev.js?

"ext-all-debug.js" is mainly used for development & debugging.

Using "ext-all-dev.js" will have any advantage?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **ext-all.js:** minified, no docs/comments
- **ext-all-debug.js:** non-minified, no docs/comments
- **ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:** non-minified, with docs/comments
- **ext-all-dev.js:** non-minified, with docs/comments, with console warnings, e.g. if you're using deprecated functions/configs or there are configuration problems. The additional console output in `ext-all-dev.js` can be really helpful, so I'd recommend it for development.
- **ext-all-debug.js**: (or `ext-all-debug-w-comments.js`) is functionally the same as `ext-all.js`, allows better debugging since it's not minified. I'd recommend it for testing purposes.
- **ext-all.js**: obviously is what you want to use in production, since the file is much smaller than the other files.

Comment: is there a even smaller version of the ext-all.js? For example a version only for grids?

Comment: @FlorianNeiss you can build a custom file with only specific components you need with [Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/guide/command). If you use the recommended application structure you can have Sencha Cmd parse your application code determine all related dependencies automatically, otherwise you can use the [`sencha compile`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/guide/command_compiler) command.

Answer (score 2):

ext-all-debug.js is not minified, has documentation, but no console output.
ext-all-dev.js is not minified, has documentation and console output.

ext-all.js is minified, has no documenation and no console output.

Answer (score 0):

the debug version of Ext is not compressed and is a lot easier to read/step through in a debugger. You might also consider using ext-all-debug-w-comments.js.